# Can we use async series inside an if statement?

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, async.js

I implemented a function where either if or else is executable in that. I wanted to use `async.series` in my code to make it look better.

```
if(payload.fb_id) {
     //all the statements here should execute
     // async.series ([...])
} else {
    if(payload.password){
    // all the statements here should execute 
    //async.series ([...])
   }
}
```

Can I use `async.series` inside the if statement as mentioned above?

Comment: That first sentence hurts my brain.

Comment: @srujana Yes you can.

Answer (score 0):

sure,its better not to repeat same code(DRY principle).try this

```
const taskArray=[];
if(condition)
{
 taskArray=iftasks;
}
else
{
taskArray=elseTasks;
}
asyn.series(taskArray, function(err) { 
//This function gets called after the  tasks have executed"
        if (err) return next(err);       

});)
```

Comment: what could be the mistake if call back of async.series gives error ?

Comment: you can identify by the error weather it is iftasks or elseTasks, As a programmer we know each function response.if you dont want to use error messages then define a variable and fill it with if or else value.